# Caller's Permission Vs Declarer's Permission

Tags: c#, permissions, delegates

I was reading about delegates on **MSDN** and saw a line that says

"**Note:**
 Delegates run under the caller's security permissions, not the declarer's permissions"

What does that mean?

Comment: Not sure... but I think that means something like :  let's say Windows  declares a method which is meant for admins usage. Now you call the method as let's say even guest. Would be kinda bad if it would allow the guest user to execute the admin method

Comment: @Osman: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the question is about Windows permissions, not .Net Code Access Security (CAS).

Irrespective what account code was run under when you created delegate (i.e. box admin) Windows permissions will be computed at the moment of actual invocation - which may be different from the one where at creation time.

Imagine that you run code that performs impersonation of an account (Windows user) to access some files:

```
// run under "account1" - has access to c:\myFile.txt
// current Environment.UserName = "account2"
Func<string,string> readAllFile = fileName => File.ReadAllText(fileName);

// start impersonation of account2 - has access to c:\otherFile.txt, 
// but not c:\myFile.txt
ImpersonateAccount("account2", readAllFile);
....

...ImpersonateAccout(string name, Func<string,string> readAllFile)
{
  // .... impersonation code omitted
  // current Environment.UserName = "account2"
  var text1 = readAllFile(@"c:\otherFile.txt"); // success
  var text2 = readAllFile(@"c:\myFile.txt"); // failure
  ....
```

In above sample `readAllFile` created when code was running under `account1`, but it does not "capture" permission of that account and hence later delegate can't read `c:\myFile.txt` which "account2" has no permissions to.

Note that delegates "capture" C# level context like local variables, which may bring assumption that other kinds of contexts are captured too. It is not the case for Window security context as well as for .Net execution context (current thread's culture for example).